# Как создать таблицу сериалов в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, список

пните меня в нужном направлении, например есть какой-либо сериал, сериал как принято делится на сезоны а сезоны в свою очередь на серии. Задача такая что хочу сделать список на сайте с выводом сериалов из БД но сама реализация деления сериала на сезоны и серии внутри БД мне не понятна. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что тут непонятного? Плоская, как блин структура - таблица сериалов, таблица сезонов, таблица серий.

Comment: Есть ссылки на примеры? Буду признателен

Comment: примеры чего? создания таблиц в БД? Книжка Поля Дюбуа

Comment: Получается для каждого сериала своя таблица?

Comment: о господи, где я такое написал? **одна** таблица сериалов, **одна** таблица сезонов, **одна** таблица серий, всего **три** таблицы

Comment: @Ипатьев сезон это всего лишь номер, не нужна для него отдельная таблица.

Comment: @teran не знаю,  в сериалах не разбираюсь, но наверняка есть какая-то метадата - год выхода, студия, продюсер. но если прям просто номер, то может и не нужна, тогда сезон идет в таблицу серий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нууу. По идее у тебя сущность это "сериал". То есть. Таблица с сериалами. Потом ты делаешь таблицу с сезонами. Будет связь один ко многим. То есть, один сериал, много сезонов. Потом делаешь таблицу с сериями. Серии цепляешь к сезонам.
Соответственно, про связи ещё не забудь. Всё это делается ещё на этапе проектирования. Таблица с сериалами. От неё проводишь связь к сезонам.
В таблице с сезонами будет столбец, что-то типо "serial-id". То есть, идентификатор сериала. Нуу и так же с сериями. Серии ты цепляешь к сезонам. В таблице с сериями делай столбец "sezon-id". Ну и в PhpMyAdmin проводи связи. От первичного ключа к тем, что создаешь. С каскадными удалениями и всё такое
P.S. Хочу заметить, что мой ответ не является образцовым "как нужно делать". Я написал "как бы я сам сделал". А дальше немного углубись в эту тему, там ничего сложного